# Is it possible to disable LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter during spring boot failure?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Is it possible to disable `LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter` execution during spring boot failure?
I made a custom `FailureAnalysisReporter` and I don't want to report twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found a way to archive what i want, simply adding: `<logger name="org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter" level="OFF" />` to my `logback` configuration will disable any logging from this class, which is essencialy the only thing `LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter` do.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by overriding the `spring.factories` configuration of `spring-boot`:

**Replacing :**

```
# FailureAnalysisReporters
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalysisReporter=\
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter
```

**With:**

```
# FailureAnalysisReporters
org.springframework.boot.diagnostics.FailureAnalysisReporter=\
your.own.implementation.of.FailureAnalysisReporter
```

**UPDATE:**

Overriding `spring.factories` means creating a `spring.factories` file under `your-project-root/src/main/resources/META-INF`. Hence `spring-boot` will load the properties overridden and keep the others unchanged.

> Spring Boot checks for the presence of a META-INF/spring.factories
> file within your published jar. The file should list your
> configuration classes under the EnableAutoConfiguration key.

See documentation : https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Comment: you mean, overriding the file `spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring.factories` ? that will do, but its not a viable solution, since i will have to maintain a custom jar.

Comment: Overriding spring.factories means creating a spring.factories under your-root-project/src/main/resources/META-INF. Hence spring-boot will load the properties overriden and keeps the others. see documentation : https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-boot/2.0.0.M3/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Comment: yes, I already did it that, `LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter` still gets executed, as my custom `FailureAnalysisReporter` as well

Comment: Do some troubleshooting to see whether the spring.factories of you project is really loaded by spring-boot

Comment: Did some futher investigation, actually, during spring factories loading process (`org.springframework.core.io.support.SpringFactoriesLoader#loadSpringFactories`) spring add up all keys found from all `src/main/resources/META-INF` resources, using a `MultiValueMap`, hence, multiple values of the same keys are stored, not overwritten.